# Possibilities of relative clause for "nichts"

Tags: grammar, clauses

> (a) Das ist nichts, auf das man stolz sein sollte.
>
> (b) Das ist nichts, auf was man stolz sein sollte.
>
> (c) Das ist nichts, worauf man stolz sein sollte.

Which ones are acceptable, and what are the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In colloquial language, you'll probably encounter all three (with no difference in meaning), but **(c)** is my guess for the canonical version.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Das is nichts, *darauf* man stoltz sein sollte" ?

Comment: No, but you'd say _Darauf sollte man nicht stolz sein_. Just be aware that those are fighting words, whereas the original is a mild rebuke or self-deprecatory.

Comment: I thought the wo* compounds were only for questions. I'll try to search for more information to correct my misunderstanding.

Comment: This relates to another recent question. For sure, wo- isn't used for questions only. Think 'whereby', which can be used to form a question or to make a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, some further notes:

This is more generic and is not restricted to "nichts".

> Worauf[or Auf was] wartest du noch?
>   Worauf[or Auf was] stehst du? (true for both spatial and figurative uses)
>   Worauf[or Auf was] es an kommt?

That said, there are still phrases where it would sound a little odd to use "auf was", for instance:

> Worauf du dich verlassen kannst.

Though, admittedly, when rephrasing the sentence you, again, can use both variants:

> Darauf[or Auf das] kannst du dich verlassen.

Still, remember it's colloquialism and you would be well-advised to go with *worauf* when being uncertain.

Finally a note on whether to go with "auf das" or "auf was".
There's a rule of thumb to take *was* instead of *das* after demonstrative pronouns, e.g.:

> Das, was du hier siehst...

So, regarding the rule of thumb you would definitely say

> Das, auf was ich stolz bin...

In the sentence "Das ist nichts, ..." it sounds OK to use *das*, though. And indeed it has more Google hits. I'm not sure why you rather take the relative pronoun *das* in that case.